# Game of chance probability

Tags: probability

Peter and Paula play a game of chance that consists of several rounds.
Each individual round is won, with equal probabilities of $1/2$, by either Peter or
Paula; the winner then receives one point. Successive rounds are independent.
Each has staked $50$ for a total of $100$, and they agree that the game ends as
soon as one of them has won a total of $5$ points; this player then receives the
$100$. After they have completed four rounds, of which Peter has won three
and Paula only one, a fire breaks out so that they cannot continue their game.
a. How should the $100$ be divided between Peter and Paula?

Comment: If they continued playing, what would be the probability for Peter to win the game?

Comment: i understand it is a problem of points but haven't really grasped the concept yet

Comment: Think of all the possible scenarios in which Peter could lose if they went on playing. E.g. one scenario would be for Paula to win the 4 next rounds in a row. What would be the other scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the questions that Pierre de Fermat and Blaise Pascal discussed in the 17th century.  There are several approaches which give the same answer, but this is my preference:

Rather than "first to five", consider a "play nine rounds" rule. Then of the remaining five rounds, Peter will win the game if he wins two or more of them and Paula will win the game if Peter wins one or zero more rounds.  This latter event has probability $\dfrac{{5 \choose 1}+ {5 \choose 0}}{2^5}=\dfrac{3}{16}$ and so Paula should get $18.75$ and Peter should get the other $81.25$.